# Azure Notificationhub - PN send working in sandbox but not in production

Tags: c#, azure, push-notification, azure-notificationhub

I am using Azure NotificationHub for sending PN to iOS devices. I was able to send PN successfully till I was using sandbox mode. But post moving to Production, the send is not working. Anyone facing this same issue ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did a lot of R&D and got my answer [here](http://ankitagrawal57.blogspot.com/2014/11/azure-notificationhub-sending-push.html)